# Inconsistent dates in Python, Mule?

Tags: python, date, datetime, mule

**In a nutshell:** How can I get a reliable date out of Python code that needs to run *both* in a normal Python interpreter *and* within Mule (specifically, [MuleSoft Anypoint Studio](https://www.mulesoft.com/platform/studio), which is supposed to interpret it as Jython)?

**Verbose mode:** As part of a Mule ESB project, I am running a few Python scripts to generate data files. These generated files are stored on the local disk, and from there picked up by a Mule flow that pushes their content to a database connection (if this seems roundabout, there are other sources that may also store these types of files in the same file system location, and I'll push *their* content to the database, too).

Here's an extract:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
...
this_date = dt.today()
if (this_date.year<1900): this_date.year += 1900 # Mule has a weird offset...?
...
print(str(date.year))
...
```

Now, with that comment, you can see I'm already having trouble. When I run the code in Python, I get 2015 as year; but when I run the same code through Mule (which I presume is using a Jython interpreter), the year becomes 115 so I add 1900.

This worked fine a month ago (over a course of many days). Today I found out that (when running through Mule) the "today()" method in the script returns not "2015-11-12" but rather "2015-10-05". Tomorrow, I will see how this date changes.

Now I'm stumped as to how I can get a reliable date out of this -- ideally it should work in *both* Python *and* Jython, but if I have to choose, Jython is the key thing.

*Update:* Nope. The new code works when run as Python from my text editor, but when interpreted by Mule, I get:

```
javax.script.ScriptException:
AttributeError: 'java.sql.Timestamp' object has no attribute 'replace'
in <script> at line number 15
```

And line 15 is of course the one with J.F. Sebastian's suggested change. *Man*, this interpreter bugs me, I never know what will be misunderstood. :(

Comment: where is the other end point of your application?

Comment: I've tried to explain the data end points better.

Answer (score 1):

The code (`this_date.year += 1900`) fails in Python (both on Jython and CPython implementations -- I don't know what is Mule). `datetime.datetime()` is immutable in Python.

Use `this_date = this_date.replace(year=this_date.year + 1900)` instead of `this_date.year += 1900`. Though you shouldn't need it: again, both Jython and CPython produce 2015 on my system. There is no difference between Jython/CPython in this case:

```
from datetime import date, datetime

print date.today()
print datetime.now()
```

Comment: Nope. The new code works when run as Python from my text editor, but when interpreted by Mule, I get:
<<javax.script.ScriptException: AttributeError: 'java.sql.Timestamp' object has no attribute 'replace' in <script> at line number 15>>
Man, I hate this interpreter, I never know what will be misunderstood. :(

Comment: @KlaymenDK: your question is about Mule, not about Python,  Jython (2.5+) then. Put the word Mule into the title and provide the link to its home page in the question.